# What is the benefit of classes in a short program like this

Tags: python-3.x, class

I'm trying to understand the purpose of classes. I've made a single program were i have two employees and i want to print all information about those two employes. However i wanted to do that using classes but i dont know if i should do that because my program is too short. Is there any benefit of creating classes using a simple program like the one i did? And if there are benefits what should be the structure of a given class for that program?

```
class employee:
  pass

emp1=employee()
emp2=employee()

#information for employee 1

emp1.firstname='Luís'
emp1.lastname='Lopes'
emp1.height='176' #mesured in cm
emp1.weight='80' #mesured in kg
emp1.email='luislopes28@hotmail.com'
emp1.feupgrade=12 # in a scale from 0 to 20

#information for employee2
emp2.firstname='Daniel'
emp2.lastname='Pinhel'
emp2.height='166' #mesured in cm
emp2.weight='63' #mesured in kg
emp2.email='danielpinhell@gmail.com'
emp2.feupgrade=13 # in a scale from 0 to 20

print(emp1.firstname,emp1.lastname,emp1.height,emp1.weight,emp1.email,emp1.feupgrade)

print(emp2.firstname,emp2.lastname,emp2.height,emp2.weight,emp2.email,emp2.feupgrade)
```

I expect to have a code much more simple and easier to understand by using classes definitions

Comment: Concepts of classes has nothing to do with length of programs. There are plenty of benefits of `object oriented design and programming`, and you will be able to leverage those if you follow OOP. I would recommend reading a bit more on OOP, and you'll be able to answer this yourself.

Comment: The way you have used them, no benefit at all.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use class when we have too much objects to create; in this case we can use dictionary for exemple

```
d={ "emp1":['Luís','Lopes','176','80','luislopes28@hotmail.com',12 ],"emp2":['Daniel','Pinhel','166','63','danielpinhell@gmail.com',13]}
```

but here you should put the attributes in order and you can't call them by name as you do with class